# How to use SCons from Python?

Tags: python, scons

I would like to use Scons as a builder directly from Python without using the Sconstruct file.

The example is very simple. I have a `foo.c` and I would like to build it using `/usr/local/bin/mycompiler`.

I tried to do `from scons import <tab>` but it seems nothing is imported.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not a supported use model.

If you want to launch SCons from python use something like this (or more complicated if your needs are more complicated)

```
os.system("scons")
```